# Decomposable set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $[0,T]$ be an interval of $\mathbb{R}$, a subset $M$ of $L^1([0,T], \mathbb{R}^n)$ or $C([0,T],\mathbb{R}^n)$ is decomposable iff for every mesurable set $A$ of $[0,T]$ and every functions $u, v \in M$ we have
\begin{equation}
u.\chi_A + v. (1-\chi_A) \in M
\end{equation}
I want to chek if the set of absolutely continuous functions from $[0,T]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ havig the same value $x_0$ in $0$ noting by $AB(x_0)$ is decomposable. my proof is the following but i am not sur if it is correct

Let $u, v \in AB(x_0)$ then 
\begin{equation}
u(t) = x_0 + \int_0^t u'(s) ds
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
v(t)= x_0 + \int_0^t v'(s) ds
\end{equation}
Let $A$ a measurable subset of $[0,T]$ proving that $u.\chi_A + v .(1- \chi_A) \in AB(x_0)$ i.e
\begin{equation}
u(t). \chi_A(t) + v(t)(1-\chi_A(t)) = x_0+ \int_0^t [u(s)\chi_A(s) + v(s)(1-\chi_A(s))]'ds
\end{equation}
startig from the left hand
\begin{equation}
u(t). \chi_A(t) + v(t)(1-\chi_A(t)) =x_0 + \int_0^t u'(s) ds . \chi_A(t) + \int_0^t v'(s) ds (1- \chi_A(t))
\end{equation}
then ( i guss that this step is wrong)
\begin{equation}
u(t). \chi_A(t) + v(t)(1-\chi_A(t)) =x_0 + \int_0^t u'(s) . \chi_A(s) ds + \int_0^t v'(s) . (1- \chi_A(s))ds = x_0 + \int_0^t u'(s) . \chi_A(s) + v'(s) . (1- \chi_A(s))ds
\end{equation}
since $[u(t). \chi_A(t) + v(t)(1-\chi_A(t))]'=u'(t). \chi_A(t) + v'(t)(1-\chi_A(t))$
then
\begin{equation}
u(t). \chi_A(t) + v(t)(1-\chi_A(t)) =x_0 + \int_0^t [u(s) . \chi_A(s) + v(s) . (1- \chi_A(s))]'ds
\end{equation}
hance $u.\chi_A + v . (1 -\chi_A) \in AB(x_0)$ which mean that $AB(x_0)$ is decomposable.
Thank you so much.

Comment: No, it is not decomposable, since $u \, \chi_A + v \, (1-\chi_A)$ might not even be continuous.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for pointing out that for me, when i revised my book, i found that he defined decomposable set only on $L^p$ or $M$(the set of measurabal functions), do you think that means we cannot defined decomposable set elswhere !

Comment: I think so. If you have a decomposable set and all functions in this set are continuous, then this set should be a singleton.

Comment: very interesting remark, i think you just lead me to a possible unique solution, thank you .